# is this responsive design possible?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a problem with this responsive layout

**[IMAGE - what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay7lr.png)**

**[IMAGE - what is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3fIs.png)**

**The problem is the height of `div.description`**

Image needs to be `width:25%;` and `height:auto;`
`div.description` should be as height as image and `width:75%;`

```
<div id="images">
    <a href="/klinika-anesteziologie-a-intenzivnej-mediciny/" class="rotate">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/1SIYe1c.png" border="0"> 
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <div class="normal_description">Klinika anesteziológie a intenzívnej medicíny</div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="/klinika-cievnej-chirurgie/" class="rotate">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/1SIYe1c.png" border="0"> 
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <div class="normal_description">Klinika cievnej chirurgie</div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="/kardiologicke-oddelenie/" class="rotate">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/1SIYe1c.png" border="0"> 
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <div class="normal_description">Klinika kardiológie</div>
            <div class="hover_description">
                Angiologické oddelenie<br>
                Arytmologické oddelenie<br>
                Kardiologické oddelenie
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="/kardiochirurgicke-oddelenie/" class="rotate">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/1SIYe1c.png" border="0"> 
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <div class="normal_description">Klinika srdcovej chirurgie</div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="/osetrovatelstvo/" class="rotate">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/1SIYe1c.png" border="0"> 
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <div class="normal_description">Úsek ošetrovatestva</div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </a>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

link - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3xgt/)

Comment: It's still too vague... what is the difference in what you want? I don't get it.

Comment: div.description is not height as image height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just add the background-color to the `a.rotate` element instead? The image will overlay the background-color and you get what you want.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3xgt/4/)

Edit re. comments:

So you also need vertical centering of a block-level element in side a block-level parent of variable height. This is not easy and might warrant a question of its own (but look for existing answers first, there are quite a few).

My first thought would be css-tables as described [here](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/), but there seems to be a problem with display table-cell and images that adds some unwanted padding. I've updated the fiddle again to demonstrate:

[Updated fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/L3xgt/8/)

I would suggest using the (flawed) solution I have provided in the second fiddle, and then asking a new question regarding the unwanted padding.

Comment: Exacly what I was about to answer. +1

Comment: with this solution, I will have problem with description align (horizontaly)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How should it be aligned?

Comment: I want to horizontally center it to middle

Comment: thank you for your time and solution .. I spend much more time on it than you think ... and also, when I edit this, I must solve another probles that it makes (not only unwanted padding)... your second solutionis worst, becouse there is unwanted padding and description height is not resposive, when window width is small. I want to solve it without javascript, but now see, I must use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) { .rotate[margin:5px;}}
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

On your description, add min-height, and make it as tall as your image. Then it will at LEAST be as tall as the image, while allowing it to grow if needed.